# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, edit, savechanges

I'm working on an application for insurance requests. When I log in as CommitteeMember and try to Edit a request(editing only its status to "approved" for ex) I get this error:
 Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

The line posing a problem is a like in the context class in the Data Project.

```
public virtual void Commit()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Here's my model:

```
public class Request
    {
        [Key]
        public int RequestId { get; set; }


        public DateTime Date { get; set; }


        public string nomBeneficiary { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public byte[] file { get; set; }

        public Member beneficiary { get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

        public string eMailBeneficiairy { get; set; }


    }
```

And here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult EditRequest (int id)
        {

            RequestService requestService = new RequestService();

            Request request =requestService.GetRequestById(id);

            return View(request);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditRequest([Bind(Exclude = "RequestId,Date,nomBeneficiairy,file,beneficiare,eMailBeneficiairy")]Request request)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            RequestService requestService = new Requestervice();

            requestService.UpdateRequest(request);
            return View("requests");
            }
            return View(request);
            }
```

And here's the view:

```
@model Mutuelle.Domain.Entities.Request

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditRequest";
}

<h2>EditRequest</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Request</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.status, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.status)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status)
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are editing, the object should already exist.  But it's not attached to the context; try using `Attach` to attach it first, or query the object from the context and copy the properties over.  See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) for more info.

EDIT: Per your date comment, you need to either change this to nullable:

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

And also make null in the DB, or in your controller, before attaching, default it to a date greater than 1/1/1753 (a minimum value allowed in SQL for datetime).

Comment: I used attach, the problem is with updateRequest when it reaches this line in MutuelleContext class : public virtual void Commit()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();}   Now the error is "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement has been terminated" it seems to me that the property Date was not excluded from the Edit, isn't that what Bind(Exclude) is supposed to do?

Comment: That means you have a property of DateTime; it didn't get a value set to it, so it sets in .NET 1/1/0001; datetime in SQL only goes as low as 1/1/1753.  Therefore, your controller needs to set a date on the DateTime, or you need to change your DateTime property on the EF object to nullable.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the properties that weren't being edited such as Date.I used ViewModel for the Edit and it worked. Thank you.